# magento google calendar integration

Tags: magento, google-calendar-api

I am new to magento, and working on already installed magento system. The thing is, we have integrated google calendar with our magento booking system. But, nowdays, the bookings are not getting pushed into the calendar.I also checked the configuration settings, and the username password for Google calendar are correct. So, when I go to any product, then the dropdownlist for google calendar doesnt pop up anything. Please I need some help in bringing this calendar back.

Answer (score 2):

I think you could open Firebug and try to click in the calender, then select the element which stands in your way. It could be something wrong with the HTML or CSS.

Besides that, keep in mind don't overwrite the original file as it will be overwritten again on next update. Create a new file and include this instead via layout xml.

Hopes that can help.

Comment: I didnt get you, what to select in the calendar and what to check in the HTML/CSS portion. Sorry for the inconvenience, but can yo elaborate more?